# How to pass a dynamically allocated array with "size determined at run time" as a reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

I know how to pass an array of constant size as a reference, but I want to know that how to pass an array of variable size as a reference to another function. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

For example, I have the following code snippet:

```
void y(int (&arr)[n]) //Gives error
{}

void x(Node * tree, int n)
{
     int arr[n];
     y(arr);
}
```

I heard that we can templateize the function and make the size a template parameter but I am unable to do so.

Comment: Don't pass an array. Pass a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Shivam Arora  C++ does not support variable length arrays.

Comment: I know i can do so, But I want to learn it on array. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of a variable length array in c++?

Comment: In C++, make the array size a template parameter.

Comment: You could use `std::array`, but that uses a fixed size.

Comment: @jxh That wouldn't work with a VLA.

Comment: @pyjg : Let me edit the question and it will be clear, with variable what I mean. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @pyjg VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) are *not* a standard C++ feature. Some compilers support them as extensions, but they are *not* standard and *not* portable. Don't use VLAs.

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone is jumping the gun with VLAs. It seemed to me like the question was referring to dynamically allocated arrays with sizes determined at run time.

Comment: You need to pass the length of the array as a parameter along with the array/pointer (but in C++, one would use a `std::vector` or `std::array`).

Comment: with variable size, I mean it is not constant as if like some 100, it is stored in a variable, lets say n and i have arr[n] which is to be passed

Comment: If `n` contains the size of the array, pass `n` as a parameter.

Comment: Anything wrong with `void y(int* arr, size_t n)`?

Comment: @zneak It is brittle.

Comment: The C tag should be restored and the C++ tag removed since VLAs are a C feature, not a C++ feature.

Comment: @dbush But the OP wants to pass by reference which is not a C thing.  Pretty sure they don't know VLA's are only a C thing since g++ and clang will both compile them as an extension.

Comment: If you are using a VLA, you would need to accept the array as the decayed pointer, and then cast it back to a reference to the VLA in the body of the function. So, you would need to pass the array size into the function too.

Comment: @jxh Even if i pass array size, it still shows error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is to illustrate how to work with VLA in C++ when passing it as a function parameter.

In c99, the syntax allows you to pass the size of the array as a parameter to the function, and use the function parameter to declare the size of the VLA:

```
void y (int n, int (*arr)[n])
{}

void x (int n)
{
    int arr[n];
    y(n, &arr);
}
```

C++ uses "function name mangling" as a technique to encode the parameter types accepted by the function into the function name to support function overloading. However, in GCC, since VLA is not a C++ supported feature, there is no mangling convention for it. One could argue this is a G++ bug (or incomplete support of the VLA extension), but it is what it is. To mimic the pass by reference, accept the decayed pointer as the parameter, and cast it to a reference to the VLA.

```
void y(int n, int *x)
{
    int (&arr)[n] = reinterpret_cast<int (&)[n]>(*x);
}

void x(int n)
{
    int arr[n];
    y(n, arr);
}
```

I have verified this works for GCC 4.8.

Answer (score 9):

Simple: don't. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead:

```
int get_max(std::vector<int> & vec) {//Could use const& instead, if it doesn't need to be modified
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for(int & val : vec) {if(max < val) max = val;
    return max;
}

int get_max(std::array<int, 20> & arr) {//Could use const& instead
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for(int & val : arr) {if(max < val) max = val;
    return max;
}
```

If you want this to work for any `std::array` or any `std::vector`, you can template them like so:

```
template<typename T>
T get_max(std::vector<T> const& vec) {
    if(vec.size() == 0) throw std::runtime_error("Vector is empty!");
    T const* max = &vec[0];
    for(T const& val : vec) if(*max < val) max = &val;
    return *max;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
T get_max(std::array<T, N> const& arr) {
    static_assert(N > 0, "Array is empty!");
    T * max = &arr[0];
    for(T & val : arr) if(*max < val) max = &val;
    return *max;
}
```

Your code should now look like this to compensate:

```
void y(std::vector<int> & arr) //Can be const& if you don't need to modify it.
{}

void x(Node * tree, int n)
{
     std::vector<int> arr(n); //Will initialize n elements to all be 0.
     y(arr);
}
```

Comment: This (the last two function templates) is terrible use of templates. You're duplicating code for no reason. Hide the container behind a template parameter.

Comment: @rubenvb This is more useful for newer programmers who need to understand what the code is *doing on a step-by-step level*. Hiding the types might be perfectly reasonable in more conventional circumstances, but it's not beneficial when answering questions like what OP put forth. Also, they're not doing *exactly* the same thing: the latter fails with a compile-time error, which can be beneficial if the user is certain they don't need dynamic memory.

Comment: You get a upvote for "don't". That's all that needs to be said.

Answer (score 0):

Xirema already mentioned how to resolve this using `std::vector`/`std::array`.

I don't know your exact case, so will just describe another options, despite the fact, that `std::vector`/`std::array` is the best.

## Pointers option

Here you have believe, that `arr` and `n` arguments of `y` are consistent. And handle `arr` size manually.

```
void y(int * arr, const int n) {}

void x(Node * tree, int n) {
     int arr[n];
     y(arr, n);
}
```

## Templates option

This will work, howether it will instantiate 2 templates on each new `N` value.

```
template <size_t N>
void y(int (&arr)[N]) {}

template <size_t N>
void x(Node * tree) {
     int arr[N];
     y<N>(arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: @juanchopanza : According to you the above code won't work?

Comment: Not with VLAs, which is what OP is asking about.